# Using keyExtractor, still getting warning that my items don't have keys

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am creating a flatList but still getting the warning that I don't have keys on my items.

I have tried creating a function to destructure props.

My render method:

```
render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <FlatList
          data={this.props.matches}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <ListItem
              title={`${item.deck} vs. ${item.opponentDeck}`}
              subtitle={item.record}
              keyExtractor={(item)=>item.time}
            />
          )}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

this.props looks like:

```
Matches:  Array [
  Object {
    "OTPGameOne": false,
    "OTPGameTwo": false,
    "deck": "Amulet",
    "gameLosses": 0,
    "gameWins": 2,
    "opponentDeck": "Esper",
    "time": "04/26 3:08 p.m.",
    "winGameOne": true,
    "winGameTwo": true,
    "winMatch": true,
  }
  ...
],
Headings:  Array [
  "Deck",
  "Opp Deck",
  "Win Match",
  "Time/Date",
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

keyExtractor should be on the flatlist not on the renderItem

```
<FlatList
  data={this.props.matches}
  keyExtractor={(item)=>item.time}
  renderItem={({ item }) => (
    <ListItem
      title={`${item.deck} vs. ${item.opponentDeck}`}
      subtitle={item.record}/>
  )}
/>
```